# Difference between static nested class that extends parent and top-level class that also extends that parent

Tags: java

Is the only difference between `A` and `B` the fact that `B` has no access to private variables in `C`?

C.java

```
public class C {
    public static class A extends C {}
}
```

B.java

```
public class B extends C {}
```

EDIT: I am NOT asking about the differences between static and inner classes. `A` is a static nested class and `B` is a top-level class that happens to have the same parent as `A`

Comment: From playing around, it seems that `A` can only reference static members in `C` (even if they are private). `B` cannot access anything private in `C` but can access both static and instance-level members.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yeah, that's the only difference. static members are for all intents and purposes to be considered as independent from the thing they are in (whether the static thing is a method, field, or inner type). Java's namespacing system is dependent on types. There's no way to refer to things otherwise.

'private' is complicated, but, for virtually all cases, you can consider 'private' to mean: Anything in the same source file can see it, and anything else cannot.

Thus, yeah, in your 'A' example you can touch C's private-marked methods, fields, and other inner types, and in your 'B' example you can't. But that's not really because of the inner-class-ness / staticness, it's simply because in the 'A' example everything is in the same actual .java file and in the B example they are not.

Comment: [JLS 6.6.1. Determining Accessibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) specifically states: *"[If] the member or constructor is declared `private`, [...] access is permitted if and only if it occurs **within the body of the top level type** (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor"*, so your statement of "anything in the same source file can see it" is wrong, given that a source file can declared multiple top-level classes.

Comment: If `B` is in a different package (unspecified), it also cannot access *package-private* members.

Comment: I also learned that the only things that  `A` can access in `C`'s scope are static variables, regardless of access modifiers. Also, `A` cannot access `C`'s private instance methods, but it CAN access `C`'s private static methods.